# Why does offsetLeft of the body not include the margin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I’m trying to get the offsetLeft value of several elements.  I get the expected value for every element except for the body element.

The offsetLeft value for each child element includes its own margin-left value plus the margin-left value for each ancestor element including the body as expected. However offsetLeft for the body element does not include its own margin-left value of 2px and returns 0.

Why does offsetLeft of the body not include the margin?

Developer tools shows the body element has a margin of 2px for all 4 sides.

Note I see a different issue for margin-top but I assume that is because of margin collapsing.

I get the same results in both Chrome and Firefox.

Here are the results from the code.

body **offset left: 0** top: 0 width: 400 height: 400 **margin-left: 2px**
div1 **offset left: 7** top: 5 width: 390 height: 18 **margin-left: 5px**
div2 **offset left: 12** top: 5 width: 380 height: 18 **margin-left: 5px**

Below is the complete code sample.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            margin: 2px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }
        #div1 {
            margin: 5px;
        }
        #div2 {
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body" >
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let body = document.getElementById('body');
    let div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    let div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    let marginLeftBody = window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('margin-left');
    let marginLeftDiv1 = window.getComputedStyle(div1).getPropertyValue('margin-left');
    let marginLeftDiv2 = window.getComputedStyle(div2).getPropertyValue('margin-left');
   
    console.log(`body offset left: ${body.offsetLeft} top: ${body.offsetTop} width: ${body.offsetWidth} height: ${body.offsetHeight} margin-left: ${marginLeftBody}`);
    console.log(`div1 offset left: ${div1.offsetLeft} top: ${div1.offsetTop} width: ${div1.offsetWidth} height: ${div1.offsetHeight} margin-left: ${marginLeftDiv1}`);
    console.log(`div2 offset left: ${div2.offsetLeft} top: ${div2.offsetTop} width: ${div2.offsetWidth} height: ${div2.offsetHeight} margin-left: ${marginLeftDiv2}`);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to give much of an answer except that the [CSSOM View spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetleft) says so. On the other hand, the offestLeft/offsetTop/offsetParent spec is known to be wrong in other ways, and indeed my reading of it says that the offsetLeft values should be 0, 5, & 10, not 0, 7 & 12. So that's little help.